# Get hourly count in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with following column

id (varchar)  tnstime(timestamp) status (varchar) and status contain fixed values like completed ,submitted or failed.

How can I get the count in last 24 hour like below

```
10 - 11  --- completed 110 submited 24 failed 3   
11 - 12  --- completed 125 submited 36 failed 4
13 - 14  --- completed 156 submited 37 failed 8
15 - 16  --- completed 178 submited 26 failed 3
17 - 18  --- completed 179 submited 29 failed 6​
```

Comment: oracle or mysql? and why java tag?

Comment: Cut the timestamps with the `HOUR` function, then `group by` on it. Then simply use the `COUNT` aggergate.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you different statuses on different rows, if you want the results on the same row I'm afraid you have to write a small procedure

```
SELECT
DATEPART(HOUR, tnstime) AS START_HOUR,
DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, tnstime)) AS END_HOUR
STATUS,
COUNT(*)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, tnstime),DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, tnstime)), STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your table is defined in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id varchar(10),  /* possibly a PRIMARY KEY, but not sure */
    tnstime timestamp,
    /* Don't use a varchar if the list of status is predefined and fixed */
    status ENUM ('completed', 'submited', 'failed'),

    /* This should be unique in any case, so, let's make it the PK */
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tnstime)
) ;
```

... and we have these data:

```
INSERT INTO t
    (id, tnstime, status)
VALUES
    ('A0', addtime(current_date, time '03:23:00'), 'failed'),
    ( '1', addtime(current_date, time '10:00:00'), 'completed'),
    ( '2', addtime(current_date, time '10:03:00'), 'failed'),
    ( '3', addtime(current_date, time '10:05:00'), 'completed'),
    ( '4', addtime(current_date, time '10:06:00'), 'submited'),
    ( '5', addtime(current_date, time '10:07:00'), 'completed'),
    ( '6', addtime(current_date, time '11:03:00'), 'completed'),
    ( '7', addtime(current_date, time '11:04:00'), 'completed'),
    ( '8', addtime(current_date, time '11:05:00'), 'completed') ;
```

First approach, let's `GROUP BY` hour and status...

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(hour FROM tnstime) AS start_hour, status, count(*) AS c0
FROM
    t
WHERE
    /* Restrict to doday; the < current_date + interval 1 day may not be
       needed, because you're supposed to know the future ;-). But just in
       case time travel were possible.
       Note that current_date is today at 00:00:00. Note also >= and <.
    */
    tnstime >= current_date AND tnstime < current_date + interval 1 day 
GROUP BY
    start_hour, status
ORDER BY
    start_hour, status ;
```

This will provide as with the following results:

```
start_hour | status    |       c0
---------: | :-------- | -------:
         3 | failed    |        1
        10 | completed |        3
        10 | submited  |        1
        10 | failed    |        1
        11 | completed |        3
```

Now we *pivot these data*, (note that the subquery `q` is the previous query, minus the `ORDER BY`) and add some formatting niceties (`concat`, `lpad`, ...) to make it look as similar as possible to your request:

```
SELECT
    concat(lpad(start_hour, 2, '0'), ' - ', lpad(start_hour + 1, 2, '0')) AS hour_interval,
    coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN c0 END), 0) AS completed,
    coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN status = 'submited'  THEN c0 END), 0) AS submited,
    coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN status = 'failed'    THEN c0 END), 0) AS failed
FROM
    (SELECT
        EXTRACT(hour FROM tnstime) AS start_hour, status, count(*) AS c0
    FROM
        t
    WHERE
        tnstime >= current_date AND tnstime < (current_date + interval 1 day)
    GROUP BY
        start_hour, status
    ) AS q
GROUP BY
    hour_interval 
ORDER BY
    hour_interval ;
```

Note that the `coalesce` function will convert `nulls` (no entries) to 0.

You'll get the following result:

```
hour_interval | completed | submited | failed
:------------ | --------: | -------: | -----:
03 - 04       |         0 |        0 |      1
10 - 11       |         3 |        1 |      1
11 - 12       |         3 |        0 |      0
```

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=255cdd53352bca55462686ddc8539b35)*

---

Reference:

- [MySQL Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: start_hour + 1 will give you a 23-24 interval, otherwise you should add 1 hour to the timestamp.

Comment: Yes, and that would be right... using your naming convention. If you want, you could use a case and have 23 - 00.